# Can't delete network interface

Tags: networking, network-manager

The last time I receive an error in my browser: *Your connection was interrupted A network change was detected. ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED* Due to suggestions I disabled IP v6 in my wireless connection but it doesn't take effect.

I decided to see all my network interfaces using the command `ip addr`. It shows more than 20 different interfaces, all of them similar with last digit difference, and I need to delete them:

```
10: veth3946f08@if9: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
link/ether c2:fc:20:6f:cc:3c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 1
inet6 fe80::c0fc:20ff:fe6f:cc3c/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

So I made the next command to delete it `sudo ip link delete veth3946f08@if9` but unfortunately I got the error: `Cannot find device "veth3946f08@if9"` hmmm. I make next command to see real or virtual devices: `sudo lshw -C network` and saw those 20 connections like this:

```
*-network:2
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 5
   logical name: veth3946f08
   serial: c2:fc:20:6f:cc:3c
   size: 10Gbit/s
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
```

I tried it to down: `sudo ip link set veth3946f08@if9 down` and got the same error that Cannot find device "veth3946f08@if9"...

So, how can I delete all of the no-used or no-named interfaces or network adapters?

Added: All IP v6 route

```
it@Notebook-PC:~$ ip -6 route
::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev vethcffa914 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev veth3946f08 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev vetha3b1511 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev veth169fcac proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev veth837bcaa proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev veth7509ee9 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev veth42ac8c3 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev veth20e1334 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev veth4d2b8eb proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev wlo1 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
```

Comment: [veth interfaces is virtual ethernet interfaces](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/veth.4.html). Something is configuring them. And why do you believe that deleting them will solve your problem? This reads more or less as a x-y-question.

Comment: Because these interfaces use IP v6 too. And I like order :)

Comment: They have link local addresses on IPv6. There's no reason to believe that impacts routing. Have a look at your routing table, not your interfaces, to get an idea of traffic flows. `ip -6 route` will show you this for IPv6

Comment: See please: ```::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev vethcffa914 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev veth3946f08 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev vetha3b1511 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium... etc```

Comment: [Edit] the complete routing table into your question. Part of it is not interesting.

Comment: add to main question full IP v6 route

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119927/discussion-between-vidarlo-and-igor-potapov).